# Compare $f(x_1)+f(x_2)$ with $f(x_1+x_2)$ if $xf'(x)>f(x)$ holds for all $x\in (-\infty,0)$

Tags: calculus

**Question**: Give a function $f(x)$ defined on $(-\infty,0)$ such that $xf'(x)>f(x)$ holds for all $x$. Compare $f(x_1)+f(x_2)$ with $f(x_1+x_2)$

---

Can anyone help please. I have been trying several ideas, but none of them worked.

Maybe we can try to find the derivative of $xf'(x)-f(x)$, which is $xf''(x)$, but even though $xf'(x)-f(x)>0$, I cannnot say $xf''(x)>0$ as I have been told that differentiation does not peserve inequlity.

Maybe we can try to directly compare them with subtraction, then $f(x_1+x_2)-f(x_1)-f(x_2) > f(x_1+x_2)-x_1f'(x_1)-x_2f'(x_2)$, as $f(x_1)< x_1f'(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)< x_2f'(x_2)$, but I don't know how to continuous.

Maybe we can split cases. For the case of $f(x)\leq 0$, since $x<0$, $f'(x)>\frac{f(x)}{x}\geq 0$, so $f$ is incerasing in this case, and so $f(x_1)+f(x_2)>f(x_1+x_2)$ as $x_1>x_1+x_2$ and $x_2>x_1+x_2$. But I am not sure how to do the other case when $f(x)>0$.

I have run out of ideas, any helps is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a function $f$? If not, what about $$f(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - 1$$? I'm not sure what you are supposed to be comparing though..

Comment: Or just $f(x) = x^2$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the examples @Mattos and riri92. From both examples, I can see that $f(x_1)+f(x_2)<f(x_1+x_2)$. So how do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$xf'(x)>f(x)$ means the function $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing.
$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)'=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}.$$

For $x_1,\ x_2\in(-\infty,0)$, we have $x_1>x_1+x_2$ and $x_2>x_1+x_2$.
So $$\frac{f(x_1+x_2)}{x_1+x_2}<\frac{f(x_1)}{x_1},\ 
\frac{f(x_1+x_2)}{x_1+x_2}<\frac{f(x_2)}{x_2},$$
and then we have $$f(x_1)<\frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2}f(x_1+x_2),\ 
f(x_2)<\frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2}f(x_1+x_2).$$
Hence $$f(x_1)+f(x_2)<f(x_1+x_2).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, but may I ask your first sentence, why that means $f(x)/x$ strictly increasing?

Comment: you can computer the derivative of function $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ which I give above.

Comment: I see that now, thank you so much @Riemann

Comment: $(\frac{f'(x)}{x})' = \frac{f'(x)x - f(x)}{x^2} > 0$

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you like this answer!

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I like the answer indeed. Thank you!